# No puedo lograr que cambie el valor mediante useState

Tags: reactjs, frontend, usestate

Buenas noches soy novato y tengo que presentar el trabajo para lo que estoy estudiando. Mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo una constante y quiero que por useState cambie el valor, valor que despues paso por props a otro componente asi hace un fetch y logra un buscador. no logro que cambie le valor de "parametro"

```
 import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { useRef, useState} from "react";
import "../buscar/buscar.css"
import { Result } from '../../Paginas/Result';

const Buscar = () => {
  
const [parametro,setParametro]= useState("lisa")
const nom= useRef();


const tomarnombre =()=>{
  const Nombre=nom.current.value;
  setParametro("Nelson")
  console.log("El valor de parametro es: "+ parametro);
  console.log(Nombre);
}

    return(
      <>   
    <form>
        <input type="text" ref={nom} />  
        <Button onClick={tomarnombre} >BUSCAR</Button>
        </form>
      <Result para={parametro}/>
   
      </>

    )
}
```

Comment: El llamado `setParametro("Nelson")` hace que el parámetro cambie, pero no inmediatamente, eso causa que el componente se renderize de nuevo y por lo tanto su valor estará cambiado en el siguiente render. Por tal razón, si estás esperando que `console.log("El valor de parametro es: "+ parametro)`; te muestre el valor "Nelson", estás equivocado, así no funciona react. Es esa tu pregunta?

Comment: Gracias! si eso estuve viendo

Answer (score 0):

Mejor tira el fetch en este mismo componente y ya luego le pasas el response del fetch al componente result.

Para ello debes tirar el fetch cuando el valor de parametro haya cambiado, y no antes. Para ello usa un useEffect

```
useEffect(()=>{
    // tira el fetch akí
    .then(response => {
    console.log(response.json())
    })
}, [parametro])
```

/////// EDITO /////////

Mira, copia i pega ésto y entenderas el funcionamiento (espero, y si no, pregunta de nuevo):

```
  const [parametro, setParametro] = useState("lisa");

  const tomarnombre = () => {
     // tus cosas aquí con "parametro"
     alert(parametro);
  };

  return (
  <>
    <form>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setParametro(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={tomarnombre}>BUSCAR</button>
    </form>
    <div>{parametro}</div>
   </>
);
```

Así es como "se debe hacer". El input se enlaza con parametro, i se actualiza con un onChange (siempre se actualizará automaticamente).

Entonces al presionar "buscar" haz tus cosas, lo que necesites por que "parametro" ya está actualizado.

Comment: Hola! gracias por tu respuesta, sigo sin entender mucho pero... el fetch a que dire lo tiro?